# Why JTextArea doesn't work with JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jtextarea

Why when I add `JTextArea` to JPanel it doesn't work? When I use `JButton` instead of `JTextArea` everything works corectly. Why doesn't `JTextArea` work with `JPanel` but with `JFrame` does?

```
public class Searching extends JPanel {

    private JPanel searchPanel;
    private JTextArea addMedicament;

    public Searching(){
        searchPanel = new JPanel();
        searchPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        addMedicament = new  JTextArea();
        searchPanel.add(addMedicament);

        this.add(searchPanel);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: When I Add panel as above to frame it doesn't show JTextArea. Im just curious why when i replace JTextArea as JButton everything is fine

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? You haven't put any text in the text area, so there is nothing to show. Try adding some text to it and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

A text area will work fine with a panel.

Try creating the text area as follows:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
JScrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
panel.add( scrollPane );
```

Now the text area will be created with a preferred size. As the data is changed scrollbars will appear/disappear as required because the problem is with your code and the context of how you use your code, not the panel or text area.

If this doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.